# Setting a flag when the approval type equals 1 and no -1

Tags: python

I am trying to set a flag based on the approval type "TEST" when its value equals '1' but no "-1",am using the below but running into following error

```
flag = 'false'
ApprovalItem = [{'by': {'username': 'lnxbuild', 'name': 'Linux Build Service Account', 'email': 'lnxbuild@localhost'}, 'type': 'VRIF', 'description': 'Verified', 'value': '1', 'grantedOn': 1376515352}, {'by': {'username': 'c_ssugas', 'name': 'name', 'email': 'c_ssugas@company.com'}, 'type': 'TEST', 'description': 'Developer Verified', 'value': '-1', 'grantedOn': 1376532352}, {'by': {'username': 'ytkim', 'name': 'Ben Young Tae Kim', 'email': 'ytkim@company.com'}, 'type': 'CRVW', 'description': 'Code Review', 'value': '1', 'grantedOn': 1376514495}, {'by': {'username': 'ytkim', 'name': 'Ben Young Tae Kim', 'email': 'ytkim@company.com'}, 'type': 'TEST', 'description': 'Developer Verified', 'value': '1', 'grantedOn': 1376514495}]

if ApprovalItem['type'] == 'TEST' and ApprovalItem['description'] == 'Developer Verified' and ApprovalItem['value'] == '1' :
    flag = True
    print flag
```

Error:-

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

`ApprovalItem` is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself.

```
>>> ApprovalItem = [{'by': {'username': 'lnxbuild', 'name': 'Linux Build Service Account', 'email': 'lnxbuild@localhost'}, 'type': 'VRIF', 'description': 'Verified', 'value': '1', 'grantedOn': 1376515352}, {'by': {'username': 'c_ssugas', 'name': 'name', 'email': 'c_ssugas@company.com'}, 'type': 'TEST', 'description': 'Developer Verified', 'value': '-1', 'grantedOn': 1376532352}, {'by': {'username': 'ytkim', 'name': 'Ben Young Tae Kim', 'email': 'ytkim@company.com'}, 'type': 'CRVW', 'description': 'Code Review', 'value': '1', 'grantedOn': 1376514495}, {'by': {'username': 'ytkim', 'name': 'Ben Young Tae Kim', 'email': 'ytkim@company.com'}, 'type': 'TEST', 'description': 'Developer Verified', 'value': '1', 'grantedOn': 1376514495}]
>>> print type(ApprovalItem)
<type 'list'>
>>> print type(ApprovalItem[0])
<type 'dict'>
```

You probably want a for-loop:

```
>>> for d in ApprovalItem: 
...    if d['type'] == 'TEST' and d['description'] == 'Developer Verified' and d['value'] == '1' :
...         flag = True
...         print flag
... 
True
```

Comment: so,how to modify the condition to check for +1 and no -1 approvals?

Comment: @Haidor - how are we checking the condition that there no "-1" for type "TEST" in the above answer?

Comment: @user2639990 I do not understand. I simply copied your code from above

Comment: My goal is to set the flag when there is a value of "1" for type "TEST" and description "Developer Verified" and no "-1" values for type "TEST" and description "Developer Verified",in the above example..there is -1 as  "'type': 'TEST', 'description': 'Developer Verified', 'value': '-1', 'grantedOn': 1376532352}"

Comment: Your code should work fine then. It checks to see if the type is TEST, the description is Developer Verified, and the value is 1. If any of these is false, then the whole statement becomes false.

Comment: how does it work?there are two values for type is TEST, the description is Developer Verified...one is 1 and other -1,flag should be 'false' in the above example

Comment: @user2639990 Remember that there is more than one dictionary.

Comment: @user2639990 So the loop goes through each dictionary. flag is true because it found a dictionary with those params

Comment: I understand why its becoming a true but based on my requirement it should be a false since there should be no "-1" values for type "TEST" and description "Developer Verified" ,were you able to understand my final goal?

Comment: @user2639990 You do realise you have more than one dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You are using list to store your several *dict*. 
You can use *for*, I think, to check each *dict*.